# How to add new things in Croogo?

Tags: php, cakephp, croogo

I just downloaded and installed Croogo (v1.5.5) CMS. I have heard that its a very good starting point for any kind of website. I reviewed it and found that its doing things using plugins instead of normal MVC in cakePHP. I am wondering what is the best way to add new customized functionality in the Croogo CMS? 
How (and where) I should create new controller, models and views? Should I do all things using plugins?

Is there any good tutorial on this subject? I checked Croogo wiki but thats not helping much. 
Any help would me much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Croogo is also using the MVC pattern and extending it is very similar to any CakePHP plugin. The first sentence of the documentation page for plugins states this as well.

The only Croogo specific point for plugins is the json file which is in fact explained in their documentation.

http://docs.croogo.org/1.5/en/developers/plugins.html

Croogo came the last time I've looked at it with an example plugin, look at it's source.